# Pegar informações de vários arquivos em um diretório

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um aplicação em Java que pegue as informações de vários arquivos **`*.tif`** em um diretório, porém não consigo pegar as informações de mais do que um por vez e preciso colocar o caminho especifico de cada arquivo. Estou utilizando `Paths` para isso. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\teste2");
BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime creationTime = attributes.lastModifiedTime();

long tempo;
tempo = creationTime.toMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(tempo));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Files.Walk` e um laço de repetição. Veja:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\teste2")).forEach(path -> {
    if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
        BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        FileTime creationTime = attributes.lastModifiedTime();

        long tempo = creationTime.toMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(tempo));
    }
});
```

Comment: Deu certinho essa parte, porém não consegui comparar os nomes dos arquivos de dois diretórios diferentes. Tens alguma ideia. Fiz a comparação assim: if (filePath.getFileName().equals(f.getName()))

Comment: Jovem, isso não faz parte da dúvida inicial. Se "essa parte" deu certo, mantenha a pergunta como está e abra uma nova com sua outra dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar uma solução alternativa:

```
File folder = new File("caminho-da-sua-pasta"); //crie uma pasta
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); //crie uma lista de arquivos 

//Vamos passar num loop para analisar cada arquivo separadamente
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        //então é arquivo, não uma subpasta
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); //cria formatador
        System.out.println(sdf.format(file.lastModified())); //aqui voce tem a data formatada do arquivo
    }
}
```

Note que nesta solução, você não está prevendo a existência de subpastas dentro do caminho que você passou como parâmetro.

Espero que isso ajude.
Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @R.Santos, tenta coloca sinal de crase (`) que você consegue copiar e colar o código aqui. Ai eu te ajudo.

Comment: `if (filePath.getFileName().equals(f.getName()))`. O código inteiro ele acusa erro pois ultrapassa a capacidade máxima de caracter

Comment: o "f.getName()" são os arquivos do outro diretório.

Comment: Não estou identificando o objeto filePath, o que ele é, e o que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: Estou tentando comparar arquivos que tenham o mesmo nome independente do formato dos arquivos e se os nomes forem iguais eu pego as datas de modificações deles.

Comment: Consegui compará-los mesmo em formatos diferentes, utilizei o release, pois serão sempre os mesmos formatos de arquivo `String arqA = filePath.getFileName().toString();
                                        String arqB = f.getName().toString();
                                        if (arqA.equals(arqB.replace(".txt", ".tif")))

Comment: É isso ai.
Eu já estava pensando em outra abordagem, mas ja que você conseguiu. Parabéns.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mesmo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41815/discussion-between-r-santos-and-andrew-ribeiro).